# Why RSA key is adding in the same line(sometimes) in the known_hosts file

Tags: ssh, freebsd, scp

When I'm doing scp a file to my remote machine, Usually the RSA and DSS keys will be added in the next lines. But sometimes(very rarely) it is appending the key to the previous key. And this is causing host key verification failed.
Mostly this is happening when I'm giving port number as 24(in my case I'm using 24 as my port for scp) What could be the reason?

Comment: This is either a bug or a weird set of circumstances. Can you add in which set of circumstances this happens and which SSH client version you are using?

Comment: Are you editing the known_hosts file by hand? (Which text editor do you use for this?)

Comment: @grawity No I'm not editing manually and I'm using `vi`